# What do Daenerys' dragons eat during her stay on Dragonstone?

Tags: game-of-thrones, dragons

In [season 4 episode 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFYPuJhyRKk), Drogon (presumably) is seen attacking a herd of goats; he burns one of the goats and flies off with it. The goatherd then goes to Daenerys and brings the charred bones of one of his goats.

In [season 4 episode 10](https://youtu.be/WIPfmjt2bT8?t=3m2s) a man brings what he *claims* to be the charred remains of his little daughter before Daenerys, after which she decides to lock up Rhaegal and Viserion in the catacombs. (Drogon is roaming somewhere else at that time.)

After that, Rhaegal and Viserion don't go hunting anymore, while Drogon stays away for quite some time. Also, we sometimes see the dragons "execute" and eat traitors and enemies, e.g. after the death of Barristan Selmy (except that Drogon does not eat Randyll and <strike>Rickon</strike> `Dickon` Tarly).

But what do the dragons eat while on Dragonstone? By the looks of it, there isn't much to hunt for on Dragonstone. Do they go hunting on the main land? Have they learnt to eat what (perhaps) the Dothraki bring to them?

Comment: At the start of season three we see them catch, barbecue, and eat fish from the sea. I suspect they do the same thing on Dragonstone, which may lead to an awkward first meeting for Daenerys with the Fisherman’s Council of Kings Landing. “...Breaker of Chains, Khaleesi of the Great Grass Sea...” “*Trout Gobbler General!*”

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You're right. I had forgotten about that. See [here](https://youtu.be/54UjlYvepws?t=2m30s).

Comment: @Brythan Thanks, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know we are never explicitly told what her Dragons eat in any of the episodes. However, in Season 3 Episode 1, "Valar Dohaeris", we see Drogon fishing, cooking and eating. Though he is considerably smaller at this point it is safe to assume they could do something similar at Dragonstone especially considering it is surrounded by water.

Later on in Season 4 (I can't remember the episode) we see Drogon, again, hunting, cooking and flying off, to presumably eat, a sheep.

I believe Dragonstone was deserted when Stannis left it but the dragons could get sheep from those brought with them or from the mainland. This seems less likely as Dany wants to conquer in a more peaceful manner and so would probably try and stop them from hunting on the mainland.

Therefore, the most likely option is that the dragons are fed by Dany or her armies or they fish for their food.